# Python SLSQP, to minimize unction with extra parameters

Tags: python, scipy

I might ask a simple question, but I looked for it on the net and found nothing that explains well (I'm not a great pythoner..)

It's just that I want to minimize a function with constraints, so I use the minimize function from scipy.optimize. But I want to minimize on the variable x (the only variable), but I also would like other paramters (that I could change easily if needed).

For example, here a basic function that I want to minimize:

```
import scipy.optimize as so

def goal(x, a) : #The variable is x, a is just a parameter

return 2 * (x - 6) ** 2  + a
```

## Constraint:

cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x})

## Initial:

x0 = 10

```
res = so.minimize(goal, x0, method = 'SLSQP', constraints = cons)
```

res

Of course if I put something like:

```
goal = lambda x:  2 * (x - 6) ** 2  + 3    #so a=3
```

I got something, but I have to change "manually" the a...

I think it's something with *a or else ? (I'm not that good :(  )

Thanks if one could give me a bit of a code for that example ;)

Comment: That's covered in the [tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html). Look at the args-argument. And more important: if you only got one optimization-variable, then use ```minimize_scalar``` (your constraint is just a variable-bound which is supported there)!

Comment: ok thanks! No the function (and the constraints) won't be that easy ;) (but for the one variable function yeah I alrady know the minimize_scalar, but still thanks)